# geth error with --datadir /Volumes/XXX

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I installed Mist (geth v1.6.0-stable) on MacOs and the sync works just as normal. I'm trying to run geth and use --datadir to use a external HDD volume. This fails with the error message geth.ipc: bind: invalid argument.

```
geth --datadir /Volumes/extHDD/ - fails 
geth --datadir /usr/name/tmp - just works.
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDD is of FAT32 format. Specified param --ipcpath local directory solved it.

Comment: There's an enforced wait of 48 hours before a poster can accept their own answer. I wasn't aware of this until recently :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing your solution. To clarify for anyone reading this, you need to share your existing geth.ipc path on your local drive so the final command should look something like:

geth --datadir "/USBVolume/" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"